# Fail Implementing SqlBotDataStore

Tags: botframework

I have implemented SqlBotDataStore for bot storage but the LoadAsync method is silently failing. This is in the MessageController's POST. No exceptions are thrown anywhere, it just stops at this line, the chat bot continues as if nothing ever happened but storage does not work:

```
    var botDataStore = scope.Resolve<IBotDataStore<BotData>>();
    var key = Address.FromActivity(activity);
    try
    {
        var userData = await botDataStore.LoadAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotPrivateConversationData, CancellationToken.None);
        userData.SetProperty<Translator>("translator", new Translator());
        userData.SetProperty<bool>("autoDetectLanguage", true);
        userData.SetProperty<bool>("autoTranslateToBot", true);
        userData.SetProperty<bool>("autoTranslateToUser", true);
        await botDataStore.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotPrivateConversationData, userData, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    catch (HttpException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
```

I cannot seem to get past this and unfortunately don't have any more information because literally no error or anything happens here. When debugging it just never goes to the next line and continues execution silently.

Comment: Add a FlushAsync call after your SaveAsync: `await botDataStore.FlushAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);`

Comment: It never gets to the save. Processing stops after the LoadAsync. I just moved this code out of the MessageController and handle it only in the root dialog and it seems to work. I still have no idea why/how something fails, stops processing, yet can have no exceptions or indications anywhere of what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this github sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AzureSql) using Azure Sql Storage to store the bot state, I modify the sample with following updates and do a test, which work for me. You can compare the sample with your implementation to find differences.

***In MessagesController:***

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        if (activity.Text == "savetest")
        {
            var message = activity as IMessageActivity;

            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
            {
                var botDataStore = scope.Resolve<IBotDataStore<BotData>>();

                var key = Address.FromActivity(activity);

                try
                {
                    var userData = await botDataStore.LoadAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotPrivateConversationData, CancellationToken.None);
                    //userData.SetProperty<Translator>("translator", new Translator());
                    userData.SetProperty<bool>("autoDetectLanguage", true);
                    userData.SetProperty<bool>("autoTranslateToBot", true);
                    userData.SetProperty<bool>("autoTranslateToUser", true);
                    await botDataStore.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotPrivateConversationData, userData, CancellationToken.None);
                    await botDataStore.FlushAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                catch (HttpException e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }

        }

        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.EchoDialog());               
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

***In EchoDialog:***

```
var tval = context.PrivateConversationData.GetValueOrDefault<bool>("autoTranslateToBot", false);

await context.PostAsync("You said: " + message.Text + $"; autoTranslateToBot is {tval.ToString()}");
context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
```

***Test result:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fei. I think I found where the problem I had is. I am doing this code not on a message activity but on update user activity when the user is added to the conversation. I wanted to start out with default values as true. This doesn't seem to work because I don't think the bot data has been stored yet so the key doesn't exist in the db. I'm still perplexed why it fails without any notification and try catching does nothing.

Comment: That's why it would be great to post all your issue details and code as here the problem was specific to how you implemented it